# Actionscript... what's next

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a predicament regarding my future as a programmer, I've been a Actionscript developer for 4 years now and want to move on, the only problem is I don't know where.

Maybe some of you (former AS3 developers) already did this transition and have some good suggestions.

Thank you!

P.S. I get if this is somewhat off-topic but I really think this is a good place to ask it.

Comment: You can debug javascript, set breakpoints etc. Bad excuse :) go for html5 and js imho. Flash & silverlight will fade away.

Comment: Flash is still relevant, and from all of this it gains clarity as to its true purpose.

Comment: JAVASCRIPT https://speakerdeck.com/getify/keep-betting-on-js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a developer with 10+ years experience with flash/actionscript.  It doesn't matter that I still love it, the clients want everything to work on their iOS devices and that is just the world we live in today.

HTML/CSS/JS are the path forward and it can be debugged.  I would hold off on html5 features that are not fully supported (like canvas, svg) and learn to do everything with divs, css, sprite sheets, and js/jquery.

Recommended tools:

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) ( + plugins as needed)
- [greensock's tweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/v12/) is now available for js and faster/better then jQuery's animate.
- sprite sheets - [learn to make](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2939) and [use them](http://www.spritely.net/)

Think of divs as movieclips to hold your assets. Use greensock to animate just like you can with it in AS3.

As for debugging, use chrome and learn to use the console. console.log("test") == trace("test"). The console will also point out the javascript errors and what lines they are on.

Also Flash is not dead and is still useful if you are making a mobile app that will be exported from flash for android and/or iOS. The new version of flash I think has some sprite sheet export options as well, or at least I remember reading that somewhere.

You have to remember that with this type of work, what you do today will be different just 2 years from now. It is always moving, don't get stuck with one tool.

Also check out [labs.adobe.com](http://labs.adobe.com/) and download [Adobe Edge](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/). Edge is going to be Adobe's HTML5 version of flash.  It is currently limited but promising if you need a tool to break the ice for you.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the future of Flash / ActionScript, read the [Adobe roadmap for the Flash runtimes](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html).

> **Flash Player "Next"**
>
> While Adobe is working on releases for 2012,
>   including 11.2 and the subsequent 2012 release, we are also
>   modernizing the Flash runtime's code base in order to ensure that the
>   Flash runtimes meet the needs of developers over the next five to 10
>   years. This work is referred to in this document as Flash Player and
>   ActionScript "Next".
>
> This work includes, but is not limited to, the following:
>
> - Refactoring and modernizing the current core Flash runtime code base
> - Work on the ActionScript virtual machine
> - Updates to the ActionScript language
>
> The primary goal of this work is to provide a modern
>   implementation of the core Flash runtimes and the ActionScript virtual
>   machine in order to significantly improve script execution performance
>   and provide a foundation on which Flash can move forward over the next
>   decade.
>
> Currently, initial Flash runtime releases that result from this work
>   are planned for 2013.
>
> Adobe plans to add support for hardware-accelerated StageVideo in
>   Adobe AIR in a release during 2013.
>
> **ActionScript "Next"**
>
> The range of applications and content for
>   ActionScript has shifted significantly in recent years, while the
>   ActionScript 3 language remains virtually unchanged since its
>   introduction in 2006. Adobe believes it is time to revise the language
>   to carefully steer its further evolution towards greater
>   expressiveness as well as productivity and performance gains.
>
> From a language design standpoint, Adobe uses the following
>   assumptions as a guide for next-generation ActionScript development:
>
> - Increasing demand for long-term productivity benefits such as
>     robustness, modularity, and maintainability to complement shorter-term
>     productivity benefits characteristic of scripting languages, such as
>     speed of development
> - Demand for high performance increases
> - Demand for hardware utilization increases
>
> First, Adobe plans to make significant
>   performance increases in the short term with a goal of continuing
>   performance improvements over the long term. Performance is the
>   primary goal when we approach how to evolve ActionScript. Second,
>   Adobe aims to increase developer productivity by simplifying the
>   language, improving tool support, and boosting bug prevention.
>   Finally, having reduced unnecessary complexity, we will be in a
>   position to innovate within the Flash runtimes much more quickly.
>
> Below are a few items being explored for the next generation of the
>   ActionScript language and virtual machine:
>
> - Stringent static typing as default, with optional dynamic typing: Most
>     stretches of most programs are expected to benefit from static typing.
>     However, ActionScript 3 tends to lapse into dynamic typing all too
>     easily in places where absolutely stringent static typing would be
>     preferable. This will be corrected. Dynamic typing will still be
>     available when needed, but it will no longer be the default for
>     ActionScript, and it will need to be enabled explicitly.
> - Type inference: Type declarations will only be necessary in certain
>     strategic places. Everywhere else the compiler will automatically
>     infer suitable type declarations and treat the whole program as
>     statically typed, even though the programmer does not have to state
>     any types. Thus the convenience of untyped programming can be
>     approximated quite well, while providing the performance advantages of
>     typed programming.
> - Hardware-oriented numeric types: For example, int,
>     uint, float, float4, byte, short, long, etc. (the exact set of types
>     is still under discussion). Currently in ActionScript 3 integer values
>     can overflow into floating point values. This will be changed so that
>     numeric operations will never change the underlying representation of
>     the numeric. We foresee this addition greatly reducing implementation
>     complexity and improving runtime performance.
>
> These are just a few
>   areas that we are focusing on. We will update this document as our
>   thinking evolves and solidifies around how the language and virtual
>   machine will change.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the roadmap, and it doesn't look very promising to be honest.

Comment: The real problem with Flash and AS is its popularity among the large hardware and software manufacturers. For example, Apple doesn't support Flash, so the millions of iPhone, iPad, and iPod users won't be able to see anything made in it. A lot of companies are realizing this and are stopping their use of it and thus Flash and AS3 are dying. (It's a good thing, too...)

Comment: I agree flash on the web is dying (especially for video players - as it should).  However the platform itself will likely survive mostly because of the low cost of entry for gaming - flash player or AIR for desktop and the native app exporter for mobile.

Comment: [The plan is dropped](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1396021) I think